# plus character missing in lighttpd php

Tags: php, lighttpd

I create a php file containing the following codes:

```
<?php
print_r ($_GET);
?>
```

And I make a request from browser:

```
http://localhost/Study/php/get.php?test=1,+
```

I got the following message:

```
Array ( [test] => 1, )
```

the plus "+" is missing, but when i use minus "-" instead of plus "+" it's ok.

```
http://localhost/Study/php/get.php?test=1,-
```

generate the following message:

```
Array ( [test] => 1,- )
```

I use lighttpd with php.

Comment: The plus sign is a special character in urls: It represents a space.

Comment: `+` is an alias of `%20` which is a space. Use `%2B` instead of `+` to if you want to represent a plus character.

Answer (score 2):

The plus sign is a special character in urls: It represents a space. Use the appropriate variant that uses url encoding:

```
http://localhost/Study/php/get.php?test=1,%2B
```